# How to post Multipart Form Data through python aiohttp ClientSession

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to asynchronously send some Multipart-Encoded Form Data as a post request, mainly a file and two other fields.

Before trying to use asyncio I was doing the process synchronously with requests-toolbelt `MultipartEncoder` (https://github.com/requests/toolbelt) which worked great for normal requests, but did not work when using aiohttp for async. aiohttp provides 2 multipart classes, a `FormData()` class and a `MultipartWriter()` class, neither of which have given me much success.

After some testing, it seems like the difference is that when I use the toolbelt `MultipartEncoder()` the request sends the data in the `form` section of the post request as it should. However, when using aiohttp the request is put into the `body` section of the request. Not sure why they are acting differently

```py
def multipartencode() -> ClientResponse():
        # Using MultipartEncoder
        m = MultipartEncoder(
            fields={'type': type_str,
                    'metadata': json.dumps(metadata),
                    'file': (filename, file, 'application/json')}
        )

        # Using FormData
        data = FormData()
        data.add_field('file', file, filename=filename,
                       content_type='multipart/form-data')
        data.add_field('type', type_str, content_type='multipart/form-data')
        data.add_field('metadata', json.dumps(metadata),
                       content_type='multipart/form-data')

        # Using MultipartWriter
        with MultipartWriter('multipart/form-data') as mpwriter:
            part = mpwriter.append(
                file, {'CONTENT-TYPE': 'multipart/form-data'})
            part.set_content_disposition('form-data')
            part = mpwriter.append_form([('type', type_str)])
            part.set_content_disposition('form-data')
            part = mpwriter.append_form([('metadata', json.dumps(metadata))])
            part.set_content_disposition('form-data')


        # send request with ClientSession()
        resp = await session.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
        return resp
```

How can I properly format/build the multipart-encoded request to get it to send using aiohttp?

Comment: This issue posted on aiohttp might be helpful https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3571, specifically this comment: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3571#issuecomment-456509079

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this for hours. My particular case was to send an email with file attachment to mailgun. Same thing that was addressed by the comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502672/how-to-post-multipart-form-data-through-python-aiohttp-clientsession#comment112704522_57502672). Please find below the working code:

```
import asyncio

import aiohttp


async def send():
    url = "<<mailgun_url>>"
    api_key = "<<mailgun_api_key>>"

    mail_gun_data = {
        "from": "<<from>>",
        "to": "<<to>>",
        "subject": "Subject",
        "text": "Testing Mailgun",
        "attachment": open("<<file_path>>", "rb")
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with aiohttp.MultipartWriter("form-data") as mp:
            for key, value in mail_gun_data.items():
                part = mp.append(value)
                part.set_content_disposition('form-data', name=key)
            resp = await session.post(
                url,
                auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth("api", api_key),
                data=mp,
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(
        send()
    )
```

I hope this is helpful and will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue and found there was no easy solution. What happened is that the `FormData` class adds a few other dispositions include `filename=${file_name}`[link1](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e9953768545149530c6ed45a48366a987b9b805a/aiohttp/formdata.py#L68), `name=file`[link2](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e9953768545149530c6ed45a48366a987b9b805a/aiohttp/formdata.py#L60) in [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e9953768545149530c6ed45a48366a987b9b805a/aiohttp/formdata.py#L156). There is a potential other one [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e9953768545149530c6ed45a48366a987b9b805a/aiohttp/payload.py#L295). [When payload is appended to the MultiWriter](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e9953768545149530c6ed45a48366a987b9b805a/aiohttp/formdata.py#L164), the 'content-length' is also added to the header [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e9953768545149530c6ed45a48366a987b9b805a/aiohttp/multipart.py#L898). When I run the code in debug mode, I also found the "content-type" of the payload is somehow resolved to the correct type based on the file.

I can't imagine how much other things are done by the package inherently. I would stay away from writting my own MultiWriter if possible..