# FastAPI Upload file appears to be incompatible with aiohttp multipart post requests

Tags: python, fastapi, multipartform-data, aiohttp

### Problem

I have the following api route in my FastAPI application, where I read in an Image upload using multipart/form-data encoding, and then use the associated image to make a post request to an external api:

```py
import aiohttp


@app.post(
    "/images",
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
)
async def upload_image(
    image: UploadFile,
):
    url = 'some.api.com'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
        data = aiohttp.FormData()
        data.add_field("file", image.file)
        async with session.post(url, data=data) as response:
            r = await response.json()
    return r.json()
```

However, I receive the following error:

```bash
| File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/formdata.py", line 149, in _gen_form_data
| raise TypeError(
| TypeError: Can not serialize value type: <class 'tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile'>
```

### References

I have been following the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) on the matter, which states that

> file: A SpooledTemporaryFile (a file-like object). This is the actual Python file that you can pass directly to other functions or libraries that expect a "file-like" object.

however, it seems like this isn't good enough for aiohttp.

### What else I've tried

- reading the bytes from the file like so -- `img_bytes = await image.read()` -- and using in aiohttp like so -- `data.add_field("file", img_bytes, filename='name', content_type='image/jpeg')`. This probably works, but it defeats the purpose of using a SpooledTemporaryFile in the first place (i.e. preventing reading into memory)
- Passing the UploadFile object `image` instead of `image.file`
- adding the additional fields `filename='name', content_type='image/jpeg'` alongside the `image.file` object.
- Using the [aiohttp.MultipartWriter](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/multipart.html) as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502672/how-to-post-multipart-form-data-through-python-aiohttp-clientsession) via the code:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
    with aiohttp.MultipartWriter('form-data') as data:
        part = data.append(image.file)
        part.set_content_disposition('form-data', name='file', filename='test.jpeg')
        async with session.post(url, data=data) as response:
            r = await response.json()
```

In this last case, the error is very similar `TypeError: Cannot create payload from <tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile object>`

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804). You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) helpful, reagarding FastAPI's (Starlette's) `UploadFile`.

Comment: If `add_field()` accepts a file object as an argument, you could also try using the `._file` attribute of the `SpooledTemporaryFile`, e.g., `image.file._file`, as shown  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804)

Comment: wow I love the suggestion to use the app state, does that mean the httpx async client can be shared without blocking the event loop? In general, is httpx > aiohttp? Ok cool, if reading in the bytes doesn't matter, I'll do that, it makes things easier, and I prefer that over accessing a private attribute file._file

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem similar to the one JKJK ran into, but not exactly the same. I'm documenting it here in case it's of use to someone else. The error I encountered was `aiohttp.payload.LookupError Cannot create payload from 0`.

I was attempting to make a `multipart/form-data` request without a file. Here's my code:

```py
with aiohttp.MultipartWriter('form-data') as writer:
    for k, v in data.items():
        part = writer.append(v)
        part.set_content_disposition('form-data', name=k)
    async with sess.post(url, data=writer) as rsp:
        pass // handle rsp
```

The error occurred on the third line, which is `writer.append(v)`. When the error happened, the variable v was the **integer 0**. I changed it to `writer.append(str(v))`, and the error went away. So, it seems that writer.append can only accept `str or file objects`, as other types will cause an error.

JKJK provided a `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile` object, which might also not be supported.